# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, printing

i have a panel to print in asp.net. i have tried many java script code but all the time i get inner html error. following is the code. 
error code

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined
```

button code

```
<asp:Button ID="Savebutton" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return PrintPanel();"/>
```

java script code

```
function PrintPanel() {
    var panel = document.getElementById("<%=pnlContents.ClientID %>");
    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    setTimeout(function () {
        printWindow.print();
    }, 500);
    return false;
}
```

the div i want to print

```
 <div id="printdiv" class="printable" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlContents" runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Medical Record No"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="MRNLBLp" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Patient Name"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Namelblp" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Visit Date"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="visitdatelblp" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Symptoms"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="symptomlblp" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Test Prescribed"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="testlblp" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this is failing because the following line

```
var panel = document.getElementById("<%=pnlContents.ClientID %>");
```

Doesn't return a valid element. I would debug it to verify